# Validate that CORS is enabled in Rails 6 with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cors

I have an endpoint which needs to permit requests from outside the domain.

In my `config/application.rb`:

```
    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '/api/*',
                 headers: :any,
                 credentials: false,
                 methods: %i[post options]
      end
    end
```

However, I need to write a spec in RSpec (I assume a `feature` spec) to ensure that requests from outside the domain are permitted for this endpoint.

My spec for the endpoint looks generically like this:

```
RSpec.describe FooController, type: :request do
  describe 'POST foo#create' do
    it 'should accept an external request' do
      post foo_create_path
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
  end
end
```

How do I simulate this request coming in from another domain?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Rack::MockRequest](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/MockRequest)

As: `Rack::MockRequest.env_for("https://#{host}/a?foo=bar", {}) }``

You may find an implementation [here](https://github.com/decidim/decidim/blob/develop/decidim-core/spec/middleware/decidim/current_organization_spec.rb)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out.